# Kubeflow missing .kube/config files on local setup (Laptop/Desktop)

Tags: kubernetes, kubeflow, serving

I have installed Kubeflow via MiniKF on my laptop.
I am trying to run a CNN on some MNIST data that uses TensorFlow 1.4.0. Currently, I am following this tutorial: https://codelabs.arrikto.com/codelabs/minikf-kale-katib-kfserving/index.html#0

The code is in a Jupyter Notebook server, and it runs completely fine. When I build a pipeline, it was completed successfully. But at the step for "Serving," when I run the kfserver command on my model, I get strange behavior: it gets stuck at the "Waiting for InferenceService."

An example screenshot from a successful run is shown below, where the process must end with the service being created:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSs2F.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Stuck at the "[waiting for inferenceservice](https://github.com/kubeflow-kale/kale/blob/d90310dbebc765c68915df0cf832a7a5d1ec1551/backend/kale/common/serveutils.py#L472-L473)" means that the pipeline doesn't get the hostname of the servable. You can also validate this by running `kubectl get inferenceservices`, your new inference service should have it's `READY` state to True. If this is not the case, the deployment has failed.

There might be many different reasons why the inference service is not in ready state, there is a [nice troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/kubeflow/kfserving/blob/master/docs/KFSERVING_DEBUG_GUIDE.md) at kfserving's repo.